# gnome-search custom provider for a specific user

Tags: gnome, gnome-search

I'd like to create a gnome-search provider that is specific for the installing user. I'm creating all of the required files in ~/.local/share but I don't see the search paths for these local overrides documented here: https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/search-provider.html

Are local search-providers allowed?